# Certain Mathematics symbols in Graphics labels

Tags: output-formatting, labeling, traditional-form

I want to put the following two labels in my mathematica (3D) graphic:

In $\LaTeX$ it would be:

$D^2 \times \{ 1 \}$ and $\partial D^2 \times D^1$

For the first one the hard part for me was the curly brackets.  I came up with something that works well enough but I think is not the right way:

```
Text[TraditionalForm[D^2 ] TraditionalForm[x] TraditionalForm[{1}], {0, 0, 1}]
```

But the second one currently has me stumped.  I can write `\[PartialD]` in a notebook but don't see how to use this.

Comment: I would use [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) package by Szabolcs Horvát and not bother with traditional formatting and all that.

Answer (score 1):

You may type these directly as strings with the following key strokes (including `"` ).

> "D <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> 2 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> \[Times] {1}"
>
> "\[PartialD]D <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> 2 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> \[Times] D <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> 1 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> "

You may find the [Mathematical Typesetting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html) guide and (from the menu) the *Palettes | Writing Assistant | Typesetting* palette useful. The guide and the tooltips on the palettes give keyboard shortcuts to the typesetting structures.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one I would use:

```
Cross[Superscript[D,2],{1}]//TraditionalForm

%//TeXForm
```

> [image]
>
> $D^2\times \{1\}$

Note I substituted the image for the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) above. For the second one I would do:

```
pd /: MakeBoxes[pd[n_], TraditionalForm] := RowBox[{
    "\[PartialD]",
    SuperscriptBox["D", MakeBoxes[n, TraditionalForm]]
}]

Cross[pd2[2], Superscript[D, 1]] //TraditionalForm

% //TeXForm
```

> [image]
>
> $\partial D^2\times D^1$

Answer (score 0):

```
Row[{D^2, "\[ThinSpace]\[Times]\[ThinSpace]", {1}}] // TraditionalForm
Row[{"\[PartialD]", D^2, "\[ThinSpace]\[Times]\[ThinSpace]", D^"1"}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: screenshot]