# FrameLabel that combines some text and some sub and superscripts

Tags: plotting, formatting

I need to add a FrameLabel that is "Mass lost, M_l [10^-3 kg]".  I would like to have "l" as a subscript to M and "-3" as a superscript to 10.

Comment: Look at `Superscript` and `Subscript` in the online help.

Comment: You can type this in directly as a string with keyboard shortcuts.  See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135567/certain-mathematics-symbols-in-graphics-labels/135571#135571) which shows how to do this. Use Ctrl+`-` to enter subscript and Ctrl+Space to exit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Mass Lost, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(I\)]\) \[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)kg]"
```

or

```
Row[{"Mass Lost, ", Subscript["M", "I"], "[", Superscript["10", "-3"],"kg]"}]
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked beautifully (I only had to replace "backslash[" by "[").